# How to convert a date in string format to a sub-settable value in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following column of data named `Date` and consists of the following format (object)

```
2020-09-28 21:56:00
2020-09-24 20:20:00
2020-09-24 20:20:00
2020-09-24 20:20:00
2020-09-24 20:20:00
2020-09-24 20:20:00
2020-09-24 20:20:00
2020-09-24 20:20:00
...
```

I would like to transform this to a datetime object so I can subset by date using `.loc`. Ive looked at questions that have been answered when the data is in a different format, but I'm not sure how to go about this when the date is in the format shown above. All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` should work for you. If not, then there is another reason that is not reproducible from the data you have shared. If there is an error, then please post the error message.

Comment: Your question was a bit unclear, I just realised that I think you have a dataframe with a 'Date' column as datetime objects already? If that's the case, ignore the first part of my answer and just go down to the filtering bit. I thought you had a list of datetime strings...

Answer (score 0):

The python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module will do exactly what you need.
Far down the page there is a section on [formatting codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

I believe what you need is something in the form of:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Your data.
data = [
    '2020-09-28 21:56:00',
    '2020-09-24 20:20:00',
    '2020-09-24 20:20:00',
    '2020-09-24 20:20:00',
    '2020-09-24 20:20:00',
    '2020-09-24 20:20:00',
    '2020-09-24 20:20:00',
    '2020-09-24 20:20:00'
    ]
# Your data: in a pandas dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':data})

# Iterate over the data.
datetimeObjects = []
for date in df['Date']:
    datetimeObjects.append( dt.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') )
# Create a new column of datetime objects.
df['DateTimeObjects'] = datetimeObjects
```

Or (as pointed out by @David-Erickson below) you can simply:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Depending on how you want to filter your objects, you can then create a start and end date to search between:

```
start = dt(2020,9,28)
end = dt(2020,9,30)
```

You can then create a mask and use locate to get your information with pandas:

```
mask = (df['DateTimeObjects'] > start) & (df['DateTimeObjects'] < end)
filteredData = df.loc[mask]
```

I hope this helps you get started.

Comment: Even with strings, simply `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` should work.

Comment: True, your way is much more succinct than mine! On another note... I'm not sure how he got his dates in the first place, because I would have just turned them into dt objects before he made the dataframe.

Comment: some parse as dates when reading in the data from excel, csv, etc, but it is not required and you can do it after.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can use dateutil after installed it using

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

this would be easy for direct use to convert string type date to datetime object by the below example

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
        
def getDateTimeFromISO8601String(string):
    d = parse(string)
    return d

new_yourDtList = [getDateTimeFromISO8601String(x) for x in yourDtList]
```